# Assigning values to richtextbox

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I want to assign texts to richtextbox,

```
richTextEditor.Lines[1] = "sdfdsf"; // Not working
```

Comment: "Not working" is a _very_ bad description of the problem. Explain exactly _what_ is not working. Are you getting errors? Exceptions? What are they?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, individual elements of the `Lines` array cannot be set, only the entire array itself. You can try something like:

```
string[] temp = richTextEditor.Lines;
temp[1] = "sdfdsf";
richTextEditor.Lines = temp;
```